# Выровнять таблицу по центру блока не толкая блоки рядом

Tags: css

В общем, вот есть наш сайт.И надо выровнять таблицу по центру так что бы картинка стояла на том же уровне что и без выравнивания(надеюсь понятно объясняюсь)

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="price-list-header">
    <h1>Выберите интересующую вас зону эпиляции</h1>
</div>
    <hr color="#965376" size="10px" width="88%" style="border-radius: 10px;">
    <div id="priceListText">
        <p>
            Пройдите процедуру лазерной эпиляции в нашем центре косметологии<br>
            и лазерной эпиляции ДОШИ насладитесь прикосновениями<br>
            к своему гладкому и приятному телу
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="priceList">
        <img src="leftSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="leftSideImg">
        <h2>ПРАЙС:</h2>
            <table id="priceListTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>консультация врача</td>
                    <td class="price">бесплатно</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">разовое посещение</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 любая зона</td>
                    <td class="price">2980 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
                    <td class="price">990 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>всё тело</td>
                    <td class="price">5980 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">абонемент на курс</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 любая зона</td>
                    <td class="price">14900 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
                    <td class="price">890 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>всё тело</td>
                    <td class="price">24900 руб</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <img src="rightSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="rightSideImg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#price-list-header h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align:center;
    color: #EB5674;
}

#priceListText{

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4B494C;
}

#priceList{

}

#priceList h2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#4F4C53;
}

#priceList table{

}

#leftSideImg{
    float: left;
}

#rightSideImg{
    float: right;
}

#priceListTable{
    align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 425px;
    height: 315px;
    text-align: center;
}

#priceListTable th{

}

.price{
    color: #EC5976;
}
```

[image: Что происходит с сайтом]

Comment: Ах, да, кстати, спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#price-list-header h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align:center;
    color: #EB5674;
}

#priceListText{

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4B494C;
}

#priceList{

}

#priceList h2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#4F4C53;
}

#priceList table{

}

#leftSideImg{
    float: left;
}

#rightSideImg{
    float: right;
}

#priceListTable{
    align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 425px;
    height: 315px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#priceListTable th{

}

.price{
    color: #EC5976;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="price-list-header">
    <h1>Выберите интересующую вас зону эпиляции</h1>
</div>
    <hr color="#965376" size="10px" width="88%" style="border-radius: 10px;">
    <div id="priceListText">
        <p>
            Пройдите процедуру лазерной эпиляции в нашем центре косметологии<br>
            и лазерной эпиляции ДОШИ насладитесь прикосновениями<br>
            к своему гладкому и приятному телу
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="priceList">
        <img src="leftSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="leftSideImg">
        <img src="rightSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="rightSideImg">
            <h2>ПРАЙС:</h2>
            <table id="priceListTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>консультация врача</td>
                    <td class="price">бесплатно</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">разовое посещение</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 любая зона</td>
                    <td class="price">2980 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
                    <td class="price">990 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>всё тело</td>
                    <td class="price">5980 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">абонемент на курс</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 любая зона</td>
                    <td class="price">14900 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
                    <td class="price">890 руб</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>всё тело</td>
                    <td class="price">24900 руб</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .......Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если у кого либо похожая(или даже такая-же проблема) не ставьте картинку после таблицы, а иначе будет как у меня)))
Стало

```
HTML

<img src="leftSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="leftSideImg">
    <img src="rightSide.png" alt="Здесь должна быть картинка" id="rightSideImg">
    <h2>ПРАЙС:</h2>
    <table id="priceListTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>консультация врача</td>
            <td class="price">бесплатно</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">разовое посещение</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 любая зона</td>
            <td class="price">2980 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
            <td class="price">990 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>всё тело</td>
            <td class="price">5980 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">абонемент на курс</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 любая зона</td>
            <td class="price">14900 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 дополнительная зона</td>
            <td class="price">890 руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>всё тело</td>
            <td class="price">24900 руб</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```